# Placement of high level summary for table data

Tags: tables

Trying to give my users useful information about the number of users they have in their instance. We have a page that lists the users, as well as few columns of information about them.

The job to be done most often when viewing the user page is to find a user and take action on them. But it can be helpful to see summary information about number of users etc. This is especially useful when adding or removing users.

How much emphasis should I give to the display of total number of users?

[image]

Making a new section above the table seems like overkill. But I feel like putting it between the search bar and the add user button feels a bit cluttered.

I haven't seen any great high level summary sections for table data.

Update: Found some example of a header with summary info.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It depends on the use case, Whether it plays a major role in deducing some facts.

Answer (score 2):

I would've suggested both examples if hadn't found them already.

You have enough screen real estate to go for the 'AgileCRM solution'.

I think the 'ClearMove' solution won't be as pretty when you move into number in the thousands (1000+). That would mean the digit will have the same amount or more characters than your title would have. I think this will make it look "off".

Side note though. I think your page could benefit from a title no matter the solution. I'm always of opinion an active menu item is poor indication of the users location.